# how to read configuration settings from custom hooks?

Tags: mercurial, buildbot, mercurial-hook, rhodecode

We are moving from HG to Rhodecode and we are using custom buildbot hook for building on push event. As mentioned [here](https://docs.rhodecode.com/RhodeCode-Enterprise/admin/admin-tricks.html#adding-custom-hooks) it is straight forward to add custom mercurial hook in Rhodecode. The issue is we are reading the configuration, e.g. credentials, from rc extension file through `ui.config` in hook

```
def hook(ui, repo, hooktype, node=None, source=None, **kwargs):
     username = ui.config('hgbuildbot', 'user', '')
     password = ui.config('hgbuildbot', 'passwd', '')
```

And the rc extension file is located at :
 `/etc/mercurial-server/remote-hgrc.d/buildbot.rc`

```
[hgbuildbot]
user = username
passwd = secret-password
```

With these setting in place, mercurial calls this hook and through `ui.config` we get the credentials, how can we do the same in Rhodecode: how to read from configruations from an rc extension file?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of separating code and configuration we ended up writing `ansible playbook` task that creates the rhodecode rcextension hook with configuration credentials -  interpolation -  because the separation of code and configuration was not an absolute necessity.

If it is a necessity then one possible option is to create json file which contains these credentials and read this file from the hook.